# Creating new dataframe conditioned on dataframe columns and series values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have df with index t1, t2, t3 and columns A, B, C, D, E and a series with index t1, t2, t3 with values such that

```
t1 [A, B, C]
t2 [D, E]
t3 [B, C, D]
```

How do I create a new dataframe such with index t1, t2, t3 and columns A, B, C, D, E such that each value in the dataframe depends on whether the column value is in the lists of the series. So in this example, I want the dataframe

```
A B C D E
t1 T T T F F
t2 F F F T T
t3 F T T T F
```

I know that there are functions like apply and transform for dataframes but these usually apply to each value of the dataframe rather than column values themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode the Series and `assign` a new column `val` then `set_index` and `unstack` the `A..E` value column to convert it to column header

```py
out = (s.explode().to_frame('col').assign(val='T')
       .set_index('col', append=True).unstack('col', fill_value='F')
       .droplevel(level=0, axis=1).rename_axis('', axis=1))
```

```
print(out)

     A  B  C  D  E
t1   T  T  T  F  F
t2   F  F  F  T  T
t3   F  T  T  T  F
```

---

Or you can do it with `pd.crosstab`

```
s = s.explode()
out = pd.crosstab(s.index, s).replace({1: 'T', 0: 'F'})
```

```
print(out)

col_0  A  B  C  D  E
row_0
t1     T  T  T  F  F
t2     F  F  F  T  T
t3     F  T  T  T  F
```

---

Or with `Series.str.get_dummies`

```py
out = s.str.join(',').str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

```
print(out)

    A  B  C  D  E
t1  1  1  1  0  0
t2  0  0  0  1  1
t3  0  1  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

A more understandable approach.

1. Get the index of original series (`index = series_t.index`)
2. Set the column of the new dataframe (`columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`)
3. Create an empty dataFrame (`df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)`)
4. Use `for` loop and `if` statement set each value of the dataFrame(`df`)

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

# create original series
series_t = pd.Series(index=['t1', 't2', 't3'], data=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['B', 'C', 'D']])
print(series_t)

print('----------------------------------------------')

# create the new dataFrame from the original series
index = series_t.index
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
for i in index:
    for j in columns:
        if (j in series_t[i]):
            df[j][i] = 'T'
        else:
            df[j][i] = 'F'
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
t1    [A, B, C]
t2       [D, E]
t3    [B, C, D]
dtype: object
----------------------------------------------
    A  B  C  D  E
t1  T  T  T  F  F
t2  F  F  F  T  T
t3  F  T  T  T  F
```